# Is the ntfs metadata $LogFile deletable?

Tags: windows, backup, ntfs, disk-imaging

I am willing to write an backup application that:

- read a ntfs partition without using windows api (done)
- write a bootable ntfs partition from the data it saved (planned)

i have a problem with $logfile, im scared that if i simply copy it, it could make windows believe that this partition is in a bad state and try to fix it(and would probably corrupt stuff since this scenario isn't supposed to happen). i currently have very little understanding of how logfile work except that it is some kind of transaction and it use entries sequence numbers.

my question is the following:

- **what happen if mft entries don't fit $logFile content?** (like sequences numbers)
- **can i bypass this by not copying $logfile?** or at least removing a part of it content? (i guess windows wouldn't try to fix anything but i cant be sure)
- if it doesn't work, **what could i do to make $logfile safe to copy?**